# Out-Of-Time-Correlators for free and interacting field theories

Tags: quantum-field-theory, field-theory, non-equilibrium

Consider the Out-Of-Time-Correlator (OTOC)
$$
\mathrm{Tr}\left[ - [ \phi(t,\mathbf{x}) , \phi(t',\mathbf{x}') ]^2 \rho\  \right]
$$
where $\rho$ is some initial density matrix, and $\phi$ is a quantum field. The time evolution of the OTOC is supposed to help identify when "quantum chaos" present in a system, and sometimes used to address questions about "eigenstate thermalization", or "scrambling times" of black holes.

If $\phi$ is a free (scalar, massless and in 3+1$D$) quantum field, then it is a standard result that the commutator is
$$
[ \phi(t,\mathbf{x}), \phi(t',\mathbf{x}') ] = \frac{i}{4\pi|\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{x}'|} \bigg( \delta(t - t' + |\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{x}'|) - \delta(t - t' - |\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{x}'|) \bigg) I
$$
with $I$ the identity operator, which can be used to evaluate the OTOC:
$$
\mathrm{Tr}\left[ - [ \phi(t,\mathbf{x}) , \phi(t',\mathbf{x}') ]^2 \rho\  \right] = \frac{1}{16\pi^2|\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{x}'|^2} \bigg( \delta(t - t' + |\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{x}'|) - \delta(t - t' - |\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{x}'|) \bigg)^2
$$
Three things to note:

- The OTOC is ill-defined, since we have $\delta^2$'s in the above. Presumably this is not that big a deal if one smears the $\phi$ operators with some function $f$.
- Because the above commutator is proportional to the identity, this gives an OTOC  which is completely independent of the state $\rho$ that is chosen (for example if we pick the vacuum $\rho = | 0 \rangle \langle 0 |$ of a thermal state $\rho = e^{-\beta H} / Z$, the above OTOC doesn't change)
- I know that OTOCs for free field theories are briefly mentioned in section 4.3.3 of [Maldecena et. al.'s "A Bound on Chaos"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1503.01409), but I don't find much else other than this.

Two questions:

1. Do more interesting things happen for interacting field theories (ie. you get OTOCs which are actually state dependent?). Is there literature on this?
2. I am finding it hard to find literature on OTOCs for field theories in the above spirit...why is this? Is it somehow not interesting to study OTOCS for fields like $\phi$ in the above? In my literature checks I find research on these objects of two types **(a)** many-body applications, where there are a finite number of quantum objects in a system (like $N$ spins) and so lots of the work is numerical/computational **(b)** Work involving OTOCs for black holes, which I am having trouble understanding but seems more related to the toy problem I mention in this post.

Comment: For your 2, Stanford computed OTOC perturbatively for a field theory that looks like a matrix $\phi^4$ model: https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.07687 Besides, there are also a whole bunch of papers on OTOC in (1+1)d conformal field theories, for example https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.06543.

Comment: For 1, in e.g. SYK model the Lyaponov exponent of the OTOC is temperature dependent ($\lambda_L=2\pi T$), so indeed you get state dependence.